# ¿Cómo medir el tiempo de ejecución en nanosegundos?

Tags: pascal

He desarrollado un programa para medir el rendimiento de la ALU y la FPU en Pascal, lo que hace es leer un archivo con 30.000 números, meterlos en un arreglo y luego ordenarlos por el método de la burbuja.

Las funciónes now() y time(), tienen una precisión de segundos, pero requiero una precisión en nanosegundos y pues al tratar de convertirlo el resultado da 0, porque el programa se ejecuta muy rápido.

He encontrado esta solución: http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/EpikTimer
Pero en realidad no entiendo mucho, porque no tengo mucha experiencia en Pascal.

```
program benchkmark;

uses
sysutils, Dos, epiktimer;

var
fichero: text; (* Un fichero de texto *)
linea: string; (* La linea que leeremos *)
datos: array[1..30000] of longint;
contador: integer;
i: integer;
suma: integer;
t_ini: double;
t_fin: double;
t_total: double;
val : integer;
Hour,Min,Sec,HSec : word; (*Esto no funciona*)
ET : TEpikTimer.Create(Application); (*Esto no funciona*)

begin
assign(fichero, 'Datos_enteros.txt'); (* Le asignamos nombre *)
reset(fichero); (* Lo abrimos para leer datos *)
contador :=1;
val :=0;
while not eof (fichero) do
begin
    readln(fichero, linea); (* Leemos una linea *)
    val := StrToInt(linea);
    datos[contador] := val;
    contador:= contador + 1;
end;
close(fichero);

suma := 0;

t_ini := now; (* tiempo inicial *)
writeln('El tiempo es : ',TimeToStr(t_ini));
for i := 1 to 30000 do
begin
    suma := suma + datos[i];
end;
    t_fin :=now;
    writeln('El tiempo final es : ',TimeToStr(t_fin));
    t_total := (t_fin - t_ini)*1e+9;
    write('Tiempo ejecucion: ',t_total, ' segundos', ' la suma es = ', suma)
end.
```

Agradecería su ayuda.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Lee los links que te pase.. voy a editar tu pregunta, ya que la primera parte esta correcta, pero la parte que empieza en que opinan, es un gran No en este sitio, ya que las preguntas sobre opiniones no son aceptadas. Bienvenido!

Comment: Para medir el tiempo con precisión, en Windows, puedes valerte de QueryPerformanceFrecuency/QueryPerformanceCounter, que tienen equivalentes en otros sistemas operativos. Delphi tiene la clase TStopWatch, que encapsula lo necesario. Aparentemente hay una implementación útil para fpc, aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927317/what-is-free-pascals-equivalent-of-delphis-tstopwatch